# DataFrame has two features how to add a row to split them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that contains a column called `feature` that can have more than one of them as illustrated in the image below `row 3 & 4`. How do a add a row to the DataFrame that splits the two features:
[image]

so for `row 3` as an example having:

```
sentiment = neg
feature = screen[-1], picture quality[-1]
attribute = 
category = screen
sentence = when the screen was n't contracting or glitch...
```

and `row 4`:

```
sentiment = neg
feature = screen[-1], picture quality[-1]
attribute = 
category = picture quality
sentence = when the screen was n't contracting or glitch...
```

so the idea is to add a row with the same information except for the category that now contains the second feature. The features can be up to 10.

Thank you in advance, would truly appreciated assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try split the column value by `,` then explode on `feature` column.

```py
df['feature'] = df['feature'].str.split(', ')

# If there is not always a space after comma, use `apply` 
#df['feature'] = df['feature'].apply(lambda feature: list(map(str.strip, feature.split(','))))

df = df.explode('feature')
```

Comment: Thank you Ynjxsjmh, it is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Just a quick question, how to I sequentially arrange the index again, as the two rows have the same number currently?

Comment: @NK `df = df.reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```py
df.explode(column='feature')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but try this:

```
features = df['feature'].str.replace(r'\[.*?\]', '', regex=True) \
                        .str.get_dummies(', ')
out = pd.concat([df, features], axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
                           feature  inexpensive  picture quality  screen
0               inexpensive[+1][a]            1                0       0
1  screen[-1], picture quality[-1]            0                1       1
2                       screen[-1]            0                0       1
```